# SetEditable on a jtable column does not change the column to editable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

and yet the column is not editable . Ideas?

Comment: Isn't JTable cell are editable by default? Also you are assigning "False" which may be a typo for "false" which tells not to set editable.

Comment: addColoumnBinding is not a JTable method. Maybe you could tell more about what apis you're using, and how your real code looks like (because False doesn't exist in Java, and I doubt addColoumnBinding is the real name of the method you'e using).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever you are trying to do (addColoumnBinding??) 
you are setting the column to be not editable: setEditable(false). Eventually you should do

```
setEditable(true);
```

Like @mKorbel has pointed out, the better way to customize a JTable aspect and behavior is implement your own table model extending [AbstractTableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html). 
If you do that you can implement the following method:

```
boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) ;
```

Comment: just please add TableModel if is TableColumn editable or not :-)